# Issues with libphp.so | PHP80 | HTTPD 2.4.56 on Red Hat 7.9

Tags: php, apache, redhat

Hello I've been facing an issue with php80 from Remi on Red Hat 7.9 and httpd compiled.
Whenever PHP8 module is loaded (LoadModule php_module modules/libphp.so) on httpd.conf, I get the error.
$>httpd/bin/httpd -k start
[Wed Mar 22 19:25:35.143647 2023] [php:crit] [pid 45645:tid 140029428127616] Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.  You need to recompile PHP
AH00013: Pre-configuration failed
$>/app/httpd/bin/httpd -M
core_module (static)
so_module (static)
http_module (static)
mpm_worker_module (static)
authn_file_module (shared)
authn_core_module (shared)
authz_host_module (shared)
authz_groupfile_module (shared)
authz_user_module (shared)
authz_core_module (shared)
access_compat_module (shared)
auth_basic_module (shared)
reqtimeout_module (shared)
filter_module (shared)
mime_module (shared)
log_config_module (shared)
env_module (shared)
headers_module (shared)
setenvif_module (shared)
version_module (shared)
unixd_module (shared)
status_module (shared)
autoindex_module (shared)
dir_module (shared)
alias_module (shared)

I tried using another libphp.so from another installation (CentOS7), php80 and httpd installed from yum. That one works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EL-7** is old, terribly old (~9 years) and close to its end of life (~1 year)

So I heartily recommend using a modern distro for modern features such as PHP 8

> Apache is running a threaded MPM, but your PHP Module is not compiled to be threadsafe.

**mod_php** is only available (in RPMs) as NTS, ZTS builds (threadsafe) are not available because raise too much issues (segfault) so mostly impossible to support.

See the warning on [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php)

You have 2 ways

1/ switch httpd in "prefork" mode to be able to use **mod_php**

Notice: mod_php is only designed to work with the default system httpd version 2.4.6

2/ use httpd in "event" mode with **php-fpm**

php-fpm works with httpd (any version), nginx and some other web servers

For this, you can read [PHP Configuration Tips](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/25/php-configuration-tips)

Notice:

**EL-8** now uses php-fpm by default (mod_php still available if you switch to prefork)

**EL-9** only provides php-fpm

Comment: Thank you Remi for your exhaustive answer. I better understand it now. I was able to keep the custom installation of httpd with php-fpm and it works like a charm!